# laravel 5 many to many not working

Tags: laravel-5

I have a many to many relationship between **Products** and **Categories** Table with Pivot table as **Product_Category**

- In **Products** Model:

  ```
  public function categories(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\Categories', 'product_category', 'product_id', 'category_id');
  }
  ```
- In **Categories** Model:

  ```
  public function products(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\Products', 'product_category', 'category_id', 'product_id');
  }
  ```
- In **Product_Category** Model:

  ```
  public function products(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Products');
  }

  public function categories() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Categories');
  }
  ```
- In **ProductController**:

  ```
  $data = Products::with('categories')->select('id','product_name','user_id','created_at')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);
  ```

Then i test with function below:

```
foreach ($data as $val) {
    $cats = $val['categories'];
}
```

I try to `var_dump()`, but nothing happened:

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#472 (1) {
     ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } 
}
```

Please help me

Comment: can you show me the output of `\App\Products::with('categories')->get()` ?

Comment: there is a typo Products::with('categories')>select ,, should be -> .. could that be it?

Answer (score 0):

When you have created a Pivot Model in your application, then This pivot table has a one-to-many relationship with each of your corresponding models. i.e. **Product_Category** model has a one-to-many relationship with **Products** and **Categories** Models. So, code in Products and Categories Models will be like below:

- In **Products** Model:

  ```
  public function categories(){
      return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\ProductCategory', 'category_id');
  }
  ```
- In **Categories** Model:

  ```
  public function products(){
      return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\ProductCategory','product_id');
  }
  ```

Do the changes as above and it should be working.